# "passing argument 1 of 'goodString' makes pointer from integer without a cast" compiler errors-C

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

I am learning C and I need to write a program with a function goodString, which returns 0 if any character in the string is repeated 2 or more times and otherwise returns 1, but I keep getting error "passing argument 1 of 'goodString' makes pointer from integer without a cast". What am I doing wrong? I'm fairly new to pointers, so am I using them wrong or is there something I misstyped in the code or something? Thank you for your time.

Here is my code:

function goodString:

```
int goodString(char *genString, int lenghtString) {
    int i, j, condition=1;
    for (i=0; i < lenghtString; ++i) {
        for (j=0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (*(genString+j) == *(genString+i))
                condition=0;
        }
    }
    return condition;
}
```

part of main where goodString is used:

```
char string[20], *first;
first = &string[0];
do {
    printf("Input a string up to 20 characters");
    gets(string);
    lenght = strlen(string);
} while (goodString (*first, lenght));
```

this part of main program requires you to keep inputting the string until there is no repetition of characters in the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`goodString` expects `char *` as its first argument. `*first` is of `char` type. You need to pass `first` as first argument to the function `goodString`.

Comment: oh, so I need to call the function as if the "first" variable was an int, like I only pass the address? Will the function still work good since char ranges up to 127, and adresses go up to much more?

Comment: EDIT: I tried doing what you said and it works normal now, I don't know why that is so and am a bit confused now but will look into it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Address have nothing to do with character ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This line dereferences the pointer  (sic)...

```
goodString (*first, lenght)
```

Instead, you want (sic)...

```
goodString (first, lenght)
```

A `*` in a type declaration (e.g. `char *first`) is a pointer to a type.  With a variable (e.g. `*first`, it dereferences what it points to (e.g. `char`).

Comment: haccks already answered my question, but thank you a lot for taking your time